# Pandoc Lua script to filter specific markdown sub sections during PDF generation

Tags: pdf, markdown, pandoc

I have `markdown` source and want to generate `PDF` using `Pandoc`.

I want to remove ALL `sub sections` below a specified level in the generated document. E.g. filter them from the source markdown.

Would this be possible with `Lua` or would it be better to do prefiltering using some other tools?

Comment: You could use something like this: https://gist.github.com/tarleb/a0f41adfa7b0e5a9be441e945f843299 the condition to exclude sections would have to be updated for your use-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got a suggestion from the Lua Google Groups forum which works for me:

```
local keep_deleting = false

function Block (b)
   if b.t == 'Header' and b.level >= 3 then
      keep_deleting = true
      return {}
   elseif b.t == 'Header' then
      keep_deleting = false
   elseif keep_deleting then
      return {}
   end
end
```